# Porque povoar um banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Galera sou novato em *DB*, não entendo o conceito de povoamento, minha dúvida é para que serve o povoamento do DB? Estou precisando fazer isso na construção de um *APP* mas não vejo sentido para fazer isso.

Comment: Não entendo porque o pessoal negativou a pergunta. É uma pergunta válida e que não é fácilmente encontrada na internet e/ou em livros.

Comment: Realmente, obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: Qual banco de dados? Postgresql ou mysql ou sqlserver?

Comment: Estou usando o banco de dados nativo da plataforma android, o SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine que você está desenvolvendo um sistema simples de cadastro e consulta, onde há a possibilidade de cadastrar um produto, consultar produtos cadastrados e editar produtos já cadastrados. Não é possível garantir que a parte de consulta e edição do sistema está bem desenvolvido sem testá-lo, e para isso é necessário que haja cadastros previamente disponíveis, sendo assim necessário o povoamento do banco de dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado !!